# What's the advantage of creating a one line function that contains a string, that wouldn't be achievable by just assigning a string to a variable?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I understand that a string can be assigned to a function directly, such as:

```
fun foo(): String = "Hello World"
```

But you can also assign a String to a variable directly as well:

```
var foobar: String = "Hello Word"
```

My question is, why would you ever create a function when you could just create a variable? I can't see the point in the existence of this functionality.

Comment: Do you see a specific case of this in some particular code?

Comment: I've seen it in the learnings I've been doing. I think I just dont understand whats the advantage to storing a data in a function that could be stored in a variable/value in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting thing about

```
fun foo(): String = "Hello World"
```

is that it is using the expression syntax, and is equivalent to:

```
fun foo(): String {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

While just returning a constant isn't very useful, using the expression syntax, avoiding the `{block}` and `return` statements allows much more concise function definitions in the case where the entire function can be expressed in one expression.

For example, if `foo()` was a method on a class, you could say hello with a property of that class:

```
class Hello(var what : String = "World") {
    fun foo(): String = "Hello, $what!"
}

fun main() {
    val hello = Hello()
    println(hello.foo())

    hello.what = "Universe"
    println(hello.foo())
}
```

This prints:

```
Hello, World!
Hello, Universe!
```

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about when to prefer a function v/s a property.

[Kotlin coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties) has a section that describes this.

A property should be preferred over a function when-

- the underlying algorithm does not throw
- value is cheap to calculate (or caсhed on the first run)
- returns the same result over invocations if the object state hasn't changed

In terms of an API use-case, in some cases exposing a function instead of a property might be a good idea as that gives you the scope to change the implementation of this API in future. What might be a hardcoded value today, could be replaced by code that computes the value in future.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, think about what the word coding means. Coding rules. Rules that are complicated get broken down in rules that are exactly one level below in abstraction, so that the program is as intelligible as possible.

Well, the function name is just one level above the expression. This is even more true in a language as expressive as kotlin where one line can easily be equivalent to several lines of Java.

If you are talking about strings or primitives exclusively then, yes, an attribute is a more natural choice than a function.